# How to whitelist the Youtube domain in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cors, content-security-policy, whitelist

I am using  in my Cordova application. But youtube videos in iframes do not load and. When I play click on the Play button video does not play and I am getting a bunch of errors. I see similar questions but the solutions provided there do not work for me. How do I fix this?

> This is how it looks on Android phones

[image]

> Here is how I am using iframe in HTML

```
<iframe width='320' height='180' 
   src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?autoplay=1' 
   frameborder='1' 
   allowfullscreen allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
   picture-in-picture; fullscreen'>
</iframe>
```

> Content Security Policy in HTML

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src 'self';
      data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
      media-src *;
      img-src 'self' data: content:;
      frame-src https://www.youtube.com;">
```

> My config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<name>HelloCordova</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
```

**Errors:**

```
2022-09-11 12:47:26.175 5078-5932/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id
2022-09-11 12:47:26.189 5078-5932/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js
2022-09-11 12:47:26.205 5078-5078/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource.", source: https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c? 
autoplay=1 (7)
2022-09-11 12:47:26.264 5078-5930/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://jnn- 
pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/Create
2022-09-11 12:47:26.298 5078-5932/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://www.google.com/js/th/PzKwASpP14dcK- 
4xI3W8wlArk1PaCxVzsebnznhuyzw.js
2022-09-11 12:47:26.380 5078-5930/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: 
https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu8nn6pHKRfEKrkfeeohdYrQ1W4OJI6toSqTVjYQNGM=s68-c-k- 
c0x00ffffff-no-rj
2022-09-11 12:47:26.382 5078-5930/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C0DPdy98e4c/hqdefault.jpg
2022-09-11 12:47:26.432 5078-5078/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jnn- 
pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/Create' from origin 
'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource.", source: 
https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?autoplay=1 (0)
2022-09-11 12:47:27.437 5078-5932/io.cordova.hellocordova W/SystemWebViewClient: URL 
blocked by whitelist: https://jnn- 
pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/Create
2022-09-11 12:47:27.452 5078-5078/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: 
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jnn- 
pa.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.waa.v1.Waa/Create' from origin
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some domains, try

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
  default-src  data: gap: 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://ssl.gstatic.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://jnn-pa.googleapis.com;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  media-src *;
  img-src 'self' data: content:;
  frame-src https://www.youtube.com;
  ">
```

Comment: Does not work. Is there a way to add regex as domain ?

Comment: Is it the same error now ? If so try to copy paste the google domains in frame-src as well

Comment: It partially solves the issue.

Comment: What's left ???

Comment: I had to add youtube domain in <allow-navigation> tag and bunch of other domains too. I will write an answer. Thank you for your answer @Eric